# Add different marker icons to different locations on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How would I add a different icon to each different location on my google map? I can add one icon for all the places. However I need them the icon to change per location.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var locations = [
          ['Doune Castle', 56.185096, -4.050264, 1],
          ['Holyrood Palace', 55.952715, -3.172270, 2],
          ['Royal Mile', 55.950336, -3.186347, 3],
          ['Blackness Castle', 56.005865, -3.516252, 4],
          ['Urquhart Castle', 57.324140, -4.442001, 5],
          ['Loch Ness', 57.322857, -4.424382, 6],
          ['Culloden Battlefield', 57.477790, -4.095711, 7],
          ['Clava Cairns, Inverness', 57.473366, -4.071808, 8]
        ];

        var image = '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/kilt-pin.png';

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.490671, -4.202646),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: image
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
      </script>
```

Any ideas?

You can see what I've done at:

http://temp62.clrs-hosting.co.uk/outlander-tours/

Slainté!

Comment: You have only one icon variation `var image = '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/kilt-pin.png';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put some image location URL in the locations array for the corresponding location. Then access them inside the loop with the same index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, guys. Sorry for the duplicate answer. I couldn't see it when I searched the site. Here in Scotland, it's - 5 degrees Celsius, so my brain's frozen!